# Finding Z value at specified X and Y value of Flat Plane

Tags: plane-curves, plane-geometry, planar-graphs

It's been a while since I did any work with planes and I'm having trouble figuring out where to start to find these answers or the best way to explain it. I currently have a line that moves through (0,0,0) and (240,102,65), making a 14° angle between the X,Y plane and the line created between those two points. You can get a better visual representation [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/losfw.jpg).

Now, my question is this: If I were to extend this line into a plane keeping that 14° constant over the whole plane 1. How would I find the equation of that plane and 2. How would I find the Z values at (0,102,z) and (240,0,z)?

I'm pretty sure with the equation I could solve for z at the specified points, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to extrapolate that line into a plane with an equation. Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would approach this question by considering the normals of the planes. The normal of the $xy$-plane is simply $\vec{n}_1 = \hat{k}$. How about the normal of the other plane? Well, we have an auxiliary point $A = (240,102,65)$. We want to rotate the plane so that the new plane will pass through this point. Can we form a relation between the normal of the $xy$-plane and the normal of the new plane? Notice also that there are infinitely many planes that pass both through the origin and $A$. So you have to formulate clearly which one you need.

Comment: We want to rotate the plane so that the line formed by the vector $\vec{OA} \times \vec{n}_1$ is included in both planes. Therefore, this is the vector that we have to rotate the normal $\vec{n}_1$ about. The cross product is
$$
\vec{OA} \times \vec{n_1} =  -102 \hat{i} + 204 \hat{j}
$$
and let $\vec{r} = \frac{\vec{OA}}{| \vec{OA} |}$. The new, rotated normal is therefore
$$
\vec{n}_2 = \vec{n}_1 \cos{90^{\circ}} + (\vec{r} \times \vec{n}_1) \sin{90^{\circ}} + \vec{r} (\vec{r} \cdot \vec{n}_1) (1 - \cos{90^{\circ}})
$$